# A different alteration while changing cell color of the JTable

Tags: java, swing

In my Java program, I have a problem about configuring the color of the table cell.
As you see below, I have 4 different column components in the cells.
And when I change the colors of all these cells, just column1's color changing.

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns,0){
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch(column) {
            case 0: return String.class;
            case 1: return ImageIcon.class;
            case 2: return Integer.class;
            case 3: return Integer.class;
            default: return Object.class;
        }
    }
};
```

And I have changed the cell color like that:

```
table1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorChange);
// I guess Object.class causes the problem
public class ColorChange implements TableCellRenderer {

    public final DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // Apply zebra style on table rows
        if (row % 2 == 0) {
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.decode("#F8F8F8"));
        }

        return c;
    }

}
```

So the question is that how can I change all columns' color?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if (row % 2 == 0) {
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);` The Nimbus PLAF provides table rows with alternate colors (automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you see below, I have 4 different column components in the cells. And when I change the colors of all these cells, just column1's color changing.

```
table1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorChange);
```

The renderer is only used for the class specified. The Object.class is a specified as a catch all class for classes that don't have a specific renderer.

In your case it will only be used for `String` objects. The `Icon` and `Integer` classes already have a custom renderer.

You could also add:

```
table1.setDefaultRenderer(Icon.class, new ColorChange);
table1.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new ColorChange);
```

However if you do this you will lose the custom formatting of those renderers. If you want to continue with this approach you will need an "IconColorChange" and "IntegerColorChange" renderer.

Instead, I suggest you check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for a solution that will allow you to do row level coloring while still using the custom formatting of the renderers or the table. This is no need to create a custom renderer.